# Post via a form clicked div

Tags: jquery, forms, html

I'm looking for a little help on how to post via a form some clicked divs.

```
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 1</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 2</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 3</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 4</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 5</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 6</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 7</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 8</div>
<div class="btn btn-large btn-rb-space">Item 9</div>
```

How can I populate my hidden input ?

Do I need an id for each div ?

Open to do it with jQuery or PHP.

Thanks!!

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How can I populate my hidden input ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a click event for all the divs in jQuery using on() - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This on this way I could go. But how can I populate my hidden input?

Comment: I think a little more in-depth explanation would help, maybe you are looking for something like this: `$('#hidden-input').text($(this).text());`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tTebY/

I would be able to get the div clicked for my next page.

Comment: like so: http://jsfiddle.net/tTebY/1/ ? - body isn't the best element to search under, you probably have another element that surrounds the divs

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to put inside my input more than 1 clicked div. :) Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tTebY/5/ like so maybe? - could make an else{} that removes the string again if you want it on/off toggle functionality

Comment: Clap! Clap! You got it!! Thanks!

Comment: If i click again on a clicked div is that possible to deselect if ?

Comment: of course :) http://jsfiddle.net/tTebY/6/ --- a little nicer http://jsfiddle.net/tTebY/7/

Answer (score 0):

Well no, you don't really need to give each div an id. If all you want to do is send what div's were clicked you can send all the clicks in one string or as you said in a hidden input field.

```
var clicks = [];
$(".btn")​.on('click',function(){
  clicks.push($(this).eq()); // returns the zero based index of the element
});
var clickSequence = ​​​​clicks.join(',');
$("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="clickSequence" value="'+clickSequence+'" />');
```

Comment: Thanks!
My software foudn an error at this line:
  clicks[] = $(this).eq();

Comment: @fra - I forgot to put the closing `/>` on the input element :P

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is messing with your form? My code shouldn't remove anything... The `append` function adds things...